# DateTimeFormatter and setDateTimePattern

Tags: actionscript-3, date-formatting

I'm having great trouble understanding AS3 DateTimeFormatter :

```
var df:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("fr_FR");
df.setDateTimePattern("DD-MM-YYYY");
result = df.format(date);
//result = lundi 19 mars 2012 00:01:00
```

The livedoc says that using setDateTimePattern is supposed to override dateStyle and timeStyle, and now it just seems to not give a single f*** about the pattern I setted, does anyone have any idea of the reason of this behaviour ?

Comment: Maybe you can try `dd-MM-yyyy`

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the case on the livedoc, its works now, thank you !

Answer (score 3):

You should write:

```
var df:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter("fr_FR");
df.setDateTimePattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
result = df.format(date);
```